# What is the equivalent of EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, process, exit-code

I'm starting a process and want to check its exit code for success or failure.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.Start();

myProcess.WaitForExit();

// What should i put instead of EXIT_SUCCESS ?
if (myProcess.ExitCode == EXIT_SUCCESS) 
{
  // Do something
}
```

`EXIT_SUCCESS` doesn't seem to exist, is there an equivalent or is the canonical way in C# to just check against zero ?

Comment: Well, generally ExitCode is 0 when it exited normally.

Comment: It depends on the application what it returns as an exit code.

Comment: sure but the canonical (well written) c/c++ applications typically return EXIT_SUCESS or EXIT_FAILURE, having named values would have been nice instead of raw numbers :)

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from defining EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE constants within your code. You could also define additional exit codes for common types of errors, and not just EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: In C/C++ EXIT_SUCCESS doesn't exists too. It's defined in a header. Problem is that C# lacks headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C/C++ code normally those are defined as constants in some include header that makes use of those. So you typically have something like this:

```
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
```

And similar definitions for some other possible return codes. After all, those "exit codes" are just numeric values that are defined as constants by some include file, but not a language construct.
As C# lacks includes and header files, you may want to define them manually:

```
private const int EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
```

And then just use in your code as any other constant. So your sample code will now compile and work as expected

```
if (myProcess.ExitCode == EXIT_SUCCESS) 
{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Although other answers are interesting this is the one that answers the most this question. So basically those standard constants of C/C++ do not exist in C#, you have to use raw values in your code or redefine them yourself :)

Answer (score 7):

You can find the [*System Error Codes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(v=vs.85)) reference on MSDN:

> **ERROR_SUCCESS**
>       0 (0x0)
>         The operation completed successfully.

As it's the only one code for success and other for error, the section is called Error codes. This isn't specific for C#, only for Windows.

Also note that you can scan the standard input/output/error streams for the proccess:

- [`Process.StandardError` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx)
- [`Process.StandardInput` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx)
- [`Process.StandardOutput` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

If you are using non-Windows environment, you should check the related reference.

Comment: `ERROR_SUCCESS` is a Win32 C API function return value - it isn't the same thing as a process exit code.

Comment: Hi @Dai. THanks for your comment. I didn't say that this is the same things. You can improve my answer, or provide your own, with correct link

Answer (score 0):

Before checking ExitCode, you should check HasExited property first. Otherwise, it will throw an exception.

```
if (myProcess.HasExited) {
  //then check exit code
}
```

Like @DalmTo said, the exit codes depend on the application. But by convention, the value of zero is the equivalent of EXIT_SUCCESS.

Comment: Note that the sample code has a call to `WaitForExit` befoe checking exit code.

Comment: what is your point? I guess you missed that in your answer? :P

Comment: That `WaitForExit` already verifies that the process has exited, in this particular case. Of course it's a fine point generally speaking.